# Are the languages in Eragon based on real languages?

Tags: languages, christopher-paolini, inheritance-cycle

Are the Dwarf, Ancient, and Urgal languages based on real languages from Earth, and if so, which ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ancient/Elven language is [based on old Germanic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon#Inspiration_and_influences), which is especially seen in names like Du Weldenvarden.

The language of the Dwarves, or at least their names, also seem to be based on Norse. Hrothgar, for example, was the name of a Danish king who appears in *Beowulf*.

Comment: Thanks! Dutch is related to old Germanic languages! I always thought I imagined similarities with Dutch!